# Plotting shapes on a chart in Mathematica

Tags: charts, wolfram-mathematica, geometry, coordinates

In Mathematica, I have arrays of co-ordinates for triangles such as `{{0,0}, {1,2}, {2,1}}`, which I'm trying to plot onto a chart. I need the points to be joined, and ideally the triangle made to be filled in. All I've found so far is `ListPlot`, but as it seems to be more for graphs than shapes, I haven't found a way to join all points to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the graphics primitive [Polygon](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Polygon.html). Primary usages (quoted):

> `Polygon[{pt1, pt2, ...}]` a filled polygon
>
> `Polygon[{{pt11, pt12, ...}, {pt21, ...}, ...}]` a collection of polygons

If this is the first time you've worked with graphics objects in Mathematica, you might want to look at the reference for Graphics, or for some of the tutorials linked from those pages.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like exactly what I was after.